# What do folded hands look like?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I search on Google images for "folded hands", and it gives me pictures like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

which I have no problem with.

However, it also gives a lot of pictures like this one:

[image]

which I don't understand why should be called *folded*.
Do people really call this position of the hands 'folded'? And can I ask why?

Comment: This native AmE speaker would only refer to the middle picture as _folded_ hands.  The first set of hands are _clenched_ or _clasped._  The third set are  _cupped in prayer._

Comment: The last picture reminds me, strongly, of [Añjali Mudrā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1jali_Mudr%C4%81), which is a hand gesture that is well-known around South and Southeast Asia. In my opinion, press/put your palms together is probably the best way to describe it.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and this turn of phrase has _never_ made sense to me.

Comment: Like @Adam, I am a native AmE speaker—but would only refer to the *last* picture as *folded hands*. Which is, to me, just the idiomatic phrase for the gesture used when praying (at least in a Christian context). The difference, I imagine, is that I attended a Catholic school during my formative years, and this was the only time I heard the phrase.

Comment: @Adam - I would use *clasped* for either of the first 2 pictures.  *Clenched* to me would imply the same 2 hand positions, but with a tighter grip.  *Clenched* could also be used for just one hand, i.e. a "clenched fist".  *Clasped* also works best if one of the hands is somebody else's.  I agree that *folded* would only apply to the middle one.

Comment: Note to the OP: All these comments are opinion and should be taken with a grain of salt. Obviously, even native English speakers don't often agree on exactly what words mean.

Answer (score 6):

They may not be folded in the [literal sense of the word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fold), but they are called folded by some people:

> [**fold your hands:**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hand_1?q=hand)
>   to bring or hold your hands together
>   - *She kept her hands folded in her lap.*

As to why, I can guess, but I'm not sure.

However, *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* and *Oxford Learner's Dictionaries (AmE)* give more specific definitions, which may not match the last image.

**fold your hands:**

> put them together and rest them on something

<sup>(from [*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hand_1))</sup>

> to bring or hold your hands together with the fingers bent

<sup>(from [*Oxford Learner's Dictionaries (AmE)*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hand_1?q=hand))</sup>

Comment: @VarunKN - I'm guessing that Færd grew interested in this, did some research and found an answer, but still thought it was interesting enough to post as a question. Incidentally, SE has [always considered that to be a good thing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4):

All three pictures depict *folded hands* in a general sense. NOAD defines this expression as:

> **fold one's hands** bring or hold one's hands together

although some dictionaries (such as [TFD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZp8d.png)) are more specific:

> **fold** (*verb*) (tr) to bring together and intertwine (the arms, legs, etc) : *she folded her hands*.

That said, I don't think intertwined fingers are required to use the expression.

Because *folded hands* are a relatively common gesture during prayer, I think there is a generous overlap between *folded hands* and *praying hands*. In a book entitled *Fantastic Vocation!*, Joseph Miksch wrote (the picture shown below is used in the original):

[image]

Other writers give a more practical reason; in his book entitled *Learning to Pray*, Den Slattery said that when his wife teaches children to pray, "they should fold their hands so they aren't tempted to tickle their neighbor."

Regardless of why praying people put their hands together, my point is that any time hands are pressed or clasped together in a prayer-like gesture, we could probably use the term "folded hands" to describe them – even if the person is  simply relaxing on a sofa.

I did a Google image search; interestingly enough, all of these pictures had the phrase *with folded hands* somewhere in their caption.

[image]

Comment: Now I'm confused which answer to mark as accepted. Thanks. And to add an image to your list, the reason why I asked this question was that I'd come across this expression somewhere in a book: _folded his hands into a shape like the top of a tepee_, which would be like [_this_](http://image1.masterfile.com/getImage/614-01180032em-Man-and-woman-with-fingers-entwined.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

As Adam commented, I would say "locked" or "clenched" hands for the first picture. To use "interlocked" would sound more clear than "locked". To [lock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lock) means:

> Make or become rigidly fixed or immovable: '*he locked his hands behind her neck*'

For the third picture, "hands placed (put) together for prayer" would be more idiomatic than folded hands.

To [fold](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fold?q=fold+) basically means to bend or to cover or wrap something in and the third picture doesn't show any part of a hand folded.

"She kept her hands folded in her lap." could be interpreted as the following picture.

[image]

Note: When you Google images for "locked hands", there are pictures of various hands including handcuffed (or chained) hands. It is not easy to tell which image is described by just reading a word or phrase .

Comment: I'd say all three of the O.P.'s pictures depict various versions of folded hands. The verb _fold_ is often used in conjunction with prayer, so just about any clasped or pressed-together hands might be regarded as folded, whether the fingers are interlocked or not. NOAD defines the idiom _fold one's hands_ to mean "bring or hold one's hands together."

Answer (score 2):

If you pretend that your hands are pages of a book and hold them palms-up, the hands can be considered to be [*open*](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQgYLa56vMAhXEG6YKHcbKD_0QjBwIBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpreviews.123rf.com%2Fimages%2FIrochka%2FIrochka0703%2Firochka070300028%2F799093-The-open-hands-of-a-young-woman-Stock-Photo-praying.jpg&psig=AFQjCNEEQMXFkrvjpNJsHb7snUL16ipMsQ&ust=1461743119840052). Googling for "open hands" images will show many more such pictures.

If you now mime the action of folding the book shut, you can be said to *fold* your hands.

> **Fold** *verb*
>   1 Bend (something flexible and relatively flat) over on itself so that one part of it covers another
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fold)

Your first two pictures might be better termed [*clasped hands*](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjm0f656avMAhWFnqYKHUHwD_oQjBwIBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpreviews.123rf.com%2Fimages%2Fyellowcrest%2Fyellowcrest1008%2Fyellowcrest100800005%2F7516684-Clasped-hands-in-prayer-isolated-on-white-Stock-Photo-praying.jpg&bvm=bv.120551593,d.dGY&psig=AFQjCNGDdkUNJ2MhhFy9ygZqIBKgInNkDw&ust=1461743609188564), though there is some latitude to the term *folded hands*, as you have observed.

Comment: 'Fold' a book shut? That sounds unnatural to me. Ngram?

Comment: @Mitch [Here you go.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=folded+book%2Cshutter+the+windows%2Cclose+the+book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfolded%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshutter%20the%20windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclose%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0) *Folded book* gathered more hits than *shutter the windows*, though unsurprisingly fewer than *close the book*. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Here's an example of the use of [*folded book*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=El6Sq7kUEi8C&pg=PA171&dq=%22folded+book%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyjZCkpazMAhUHG5QKHRzvDS84ChDoAQgjMAA#v=onepage&q=%22folded%20book%22&f=false) to mean one that is in a closed state.

Comment: @Mitch Besides, I'm not arguing for 'folding shut' to be idiomatic; it's just illustrative of the action.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks. Got it. Sometimes when phrases are pointed out out of context they sound strange when in context they're perfectly natural.